# AWS CLI on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (Python path)

Tags: windows, bash, amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to share `~/.aws/` credentials with both environments (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows + Windows). To do so, I've created a symlink like: `ln -s /mnt/c/Users/<user_name>/.aws ~/.aws`

From Bash on Ubuntu on Windows, when I run `which aws` I get a Windows Python path. Not ideal. How is it picking this up?

I created 2 separate Python virtual environments, 1 for Linux and 1 for Windows.

Now when I run `aws s3 ls` etc from either environment, I get the same results yay!

However, if I don't activate a Linux virtual environment from "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" and try run `aws s3 ls` it breaks because it's trying to use Windows' Python aws. I can see this by running `echo $PATH`

Can I drop the Windows Python path from my Linux subsystem safely?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51345880/8928481

Comment: Cheers @Biswapriyo , seems like this is a common issue with installs being available on both platforms. I'll give this ago.